# What changes, if any, are required to make the following Perl eval bullet proof?

Tags: exception-handling, perl

```
eval {
    # here is put some code that may throw exception
    1;  # Why is the "1;" here ?
} or do {
   my $error = $@;
   # Handle error.
};
```

1. Does the following style protect against $@ not being set
   correctly ?
2. What does the following "1;" protect against?
3. Is the "or do{" better than the saying "if ($@){ " ? If so, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ad. 1. Yes and no - [there are still some pitfalls](https://metacpan.org/module/Try::Tiny#BACKGROUND) (please read further).

Ad. 2. You must remember about returning truthy value from `eval` block because it evaluates to last value in block **unless** some code died, in which case `undef` is returned, so `1;` as last statement in `eval` block is important.

You also have to localize `$@` somehow (`my $error = $@` in your example) because it's a global variable which can be changed silently (see Conclusion).

Ad. 3. `if ($@)` can have one pitfall, i.e. it doesn't catch error when it's false:

```
eval {
  die '';
  do_something();
};
if ($@) {
  # ooops... we don't get here
}
```

while `or do { }` block will always be activated in case of exception

```
eval {
  die '';
  do_something();
  1;
} or do {
  # caught!
};
```

**Conclusion:**

I personally use "eval or do # process error" style of catching errors but common and widely used alternative, which eleminates boilerplate code, is to use [`Try::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/module/Try::Tiny). It's a simple, 0-dependency CPAN module which addresses `$@` issues. Its documentation (especially BACKGROUND section) is really worth reading as it answers some of your questions and with even more details.

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364975/is-trytiny-still-recommended-for-exception-handling-in-perl-5-14-or-later).

Comment: Great documented answer. I don't know Perl, but enjoyed reading it. :)